# Notepad++: Create shorcut to Batch file and open file afterwards

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, notepad++, python

I have a batchscript with the following contents:

```
python.exe c:/path/to/my/pythonscript/script.py %1
```

which I currently use to be able to drag-n-drop a file onto it. script.py then makes a duplicate of the file and processes it with some algorithm. Afterwards, it returns the path to the processed file on the commandline.

Now, what I want to achieve in N++ is: I want an icon in N++ on the toolbar -> When clicking this icon, I want to call the batchscript passing the filename/filepath of the currently opened file to it (which will effectively call `python.exe c:/path/to/my/pythonscript/script.py FILEPATH_OF_OPENED_FILE_IN_NPP`) and after the script is done, I'd like to automatically open the processed duplicate in N++.

I want to do it without using any sort of plugin. Is that possible?

I know it would be easily possible using some Plugins, e.g. using NppPythonScript, writing a script which calls the batchfile (using os.system("blaa.bat")) and then opening the resulting  file using editor.open('...').

Is there a way without a plugin? Or maybe by writing a minimal plugin myself in C++ (as I'm not allowed to install any plugin from "inofficial" sources).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you'd have to write a plugin. All it needs is to add an icon to the toolbar which, when clicked, calls a function performing the tasks you want. You can actually write the plugin in several languages such as Python, C#, Ada, etc. Here's some guides to writing a Notepad++ plugin:

- [Plugin to run python script example](https://mpcabd.xyz/notepad-plugin-to-run-python-scripts/)
- [Plugin Development Quick-Start Guide](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Plugin_Development_Quick_Start_Guide)
- [Plugin How-To](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/contribute/plugin-howto.html)
- [Plugin Development](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=Plugin_Development)

Update: I couldn't any examples of plugins in Python, however, it should be possible because they have demos of plugins written in odd languages such as Delphi and Ada. I pulled these links from the fourth link up above.

- [C/C++ Template in ANSI and Unicode](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/commun/pluginDemoTemplate/NppPluginTemplate.zip)
- [Delphi template in ANSI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/DelphiPluginTemplate/DelphiPluginTemplate%201.0/DelphiPluginTemplate.zip/download)
- [Delphi template in Unicode](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/DelphiPluginTemplate/DelphiPluginTemplate%202.0%20UNICODE/DelphiPluginTemplate2.zip/download)
- [C# template in ANSI](http://artiche.info/npp/NppDotnetPlugin.zip)
- [.NET template and demo in Unicode](http://www.file-upload.net/download-2120709/NppPlugin.NET.v0.3.7z.html)
- [DFPN++(library to write Delphi plugins)](http://www.cab.i24.cc/projects/npppluginbase/)

Comment: Oh, didn't know I could write a Plugin in Python itself. Ill check it out, thanks as of now. I hope it'll not be hard ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the update - I was just about to ask, because I could not find any example myself either for a simple Python plugin.

Comment: Your welcome. You'd find it hard to write the plugin _itself_ in Python(plugins are DLLs), but the very first link I provided shows how to write a plugin that runs a Python(or, for that matter, any) script. Since they were able to write plugins directly in Ada/Delphi, you _should_ be able to write one in Python, however that would be advanced stuff, and probably outside the scope of your question.